# SVG image within an object tag overlys website content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am using a SVG image within an object tag on a web page. I cannot use the img-tag, because I need to interact with CSS classes within the SVG and have a navigation option which is used on clicks within the SVG.

I used to have the SVG inline, but now I wanted to rework the page to be adaptive/responsive and thus I’m trying to use the object-tag to make it scalable. It works fine with Chrome, Firefox and Opera. When it comes down to IE I ran into problems.

Other than the other browsers IE overlays everything with a white background. This includes the navigation div I use to show when the user clicks on certain elements. I simplified everything to show the effect:

[image: How it should look like (Chrome, FF, Opera)]

This is how it should be

[image: How it looks in IE]

What IE makes of it

I tried to fiddle with Z-index on the object, wrapping the object in a different div and applying z-index on it. I also tried CSS on the SVG and the object tag, trying to set the background to transparent, none and similar things. All to no avail. The background stays white and the content hidden.

Then I found this:
http://solidlystated.com/scripting/place-div-over-iframe-in-internet-explorer/
Which leads to IE showing the content, but makes the element inactive, since the iframe prevents the links within to be clicked:

[image: IE with ifram]

The simplified HTML so far:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <h1>System</h1>
     <div class="contentItem">
        <div class="aroundSVG" style="height: 530px">
           <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/sys2.svg" id="svgObject" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: transparent;"></object>
     </div>
     <div id="showNav">
        <ul>
           <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/index.htm';
                         return false;">Line 1</a></li>
           <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/event.htm';
                 return false;">Line 2</a></li>
           <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/error.htm';
                 return false;">Line 3</a></li>
           <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/index.htm?reset=true';
                 return false;">Line 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- <iframe id="fake" src="about:blank" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; border: none;"></iframe> -->
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The SVG file:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/svg+xml"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </meta>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/svgStyle.css" media="all" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery_min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         parent.svgObj = document
         parent.svgModules = $(parent.svgObj).find(".modules");
         parent.setModClick();      
         $(parent.svgObj).click(function (e)
         {
            var container = parent.navContainer;
            var optDiv = $(".classB");
            if (!container.is(e.target)
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0
            && !optDiv.is(e.target)
            && optDiv.has(e.target).length === 0)
           {
              container.hide(250);
           }
        });
     })
   </script>
</head>
<svg viewBox="0 0 923 500">
   <g class=„classA classB“ id="gvg" transform="translate(300,250)">
      <circle class=„circle“ cx="150" cy="0" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
   </g>
   <g class=„classA classB“ id="dr" transform="translate(300,300)">
      <circle class=„circle“ cx="150" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
   </g>
   <g class=„classA classB“ id="hur" transform="translate(300,350)">
     <circle class=„circle“ cx="150" cy="100" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Is there any way to keep the toggled menu active and shown within IE/Edge (I guess there will be problems, too), or am I using the object-tag/SVG file the wrong way?

There seems no way to resolve this with CSS within IE, while the other browser keep the SVG background transparant.

Comment: Some of your quotes are curly.

Comment: To minimize the amount of typos I pre-typed in word. I guess MS auto-formated some of the quotes where I edited the class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting and researching I found a solution. I needed to make the `<ul>` element absolute in positioning and remove it from the fake `<iframe>`. Now the navigation is visible and clickable. I needed to add some CSS and fiddle with height and width in javascript/jQuery due to variable heights, but that's irrelevant.

So it worked for me like this:

```
 <div id="showNav">
    <ul style='position: absolute'>
       <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/index.htm';
                     return false;">Line 1</a></li>
       <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/event.htm';
             return false;">Line 2</a></li>
       <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/error.htm';
             return false;">Line 3</a></li>
       <li><a href=„LinkTarget“ onclick="location.href = this.href + fncTarget + '/index.htm?reset=true';
             return false;">Line 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="fake" src="about:blank" style="width: 102%; height: 103%; border: none;"></iframe>
 </div>
```

You may need to vary height, width and border of the iFrame to match your case, since you need to adjust this to make all formatting of the parent `<div>` visible.

I hope this will help someone who stumbles over the same issues.